# how do I add width values to increase by x amount?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an EFPS bar for games, and ive got JS code to get the ID of the element. This works perfect, but how do I get it to add 30% to the already existing width percent of the bar? The width it's set to by default is 18. So it should change to 48% but it replaces it with 30%. I have tried using += but that just makes it not work.

```
document.getElementById("mwfps").style.width = "30%";
```

Comment: _"I have tried using += but that just makes it not work"_ - of course not, `18% + 30%` is not a valid math operation in JavaScript.

Comment: Hi @ken, What is the width unit? Or is it just `18` as `Number`(In which case below answer would work. Or you got to tweek around my answer by trimming any of the units first and then trying

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather It is 18% I tried using px values but that didnt work at all. 
  <div class="efpsbar-bar" id="mwfps" style="background: rgb(255, 0, 0); width: 18.75%;"></div> this is how it is

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const obj = document.getElementById("mwfps");
obj.style.width = `${Number(obj.style.width)+30}%`
```

Comment: This didnt do anything sadly

Comment: document.getElementById("mwfps").style.width = parseFloat((document.getElementById("mwfps").style.width)) + 20 + "%"; has it working perfectly

Comment: Yes, It depended on what is the width and its type brother. I am glad you found it. In question the context was not enough. I assumed convert a string value to number may help.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set the width as `inline style` if you want to retrieve the percentage value otherwise you will always get the pixel transformed values and you will have to make the conversion with some math.
Then you can retrieve the `width` from style object, get rid of `%` symbol, perform the sum, and return a new percentage.

```js
select.onchange = e => {
  const width = mwfps.style.width
  mwfps.style.width = +width.replace("%", "") + +e.target.value + "%"
  const newWidth = mwfps.style.width
  mwfps.innerText = newWidth
}
```

```css
#mwfps {
  background: orange;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mwfps" style="width:18%">18%</div>
<select id="select">
  <option value="10">10%</option>
  <option value="20">20%</option>
  <option value="30">30%</option>
  <option value="40">40%</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Not even close to what I'm trying to do. That just iterates from 18, to 48, then 78. I'm not looking for a timer to change it. I'm changing it based on what a user selects

Comment: It's just an example to show how to increase from a previous value, wherever you take the value from is another matter... you did not even specifiy it in your question ... Line n. 7 is what matters ...

Comment: This is the same logic, but with a select...

Comment: document.getElementById("mwfps").style.width = parseFloat((document.getElementById("mwfps").style.width)) + 20 + "%";


This is what I was looking for. Its all good now. thanks